# Composer doesn't work after global installation

Tags: macos, composer-php

I'm a newbie. I've searched all over the place to find a solution for my issue but unfortunately couldn't find it. So hopefully somebody on here can tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I missed.

I installed composer on my local machine (MacBook Pro).
I've made it global and when I go to `/usr/local/bin` I can see the file `composer.phar`

On my desktop I've created a folder `teamleader-api`. I want to make a WordPress plugin that uses service API's.

As library I want to use https://github.com/sumocoders/Teamleader

On the instructions that I found they say that I need to go to my plugin directory.

```
$ cd /Users/myname/Desktop/teamleader-api
```

The library says that to install I need to use `composer require sumocoders/teamleader`

```
$ composer require sumocoders/teamleader
```

But when I give in this command in my terminal I get

```
-bash: composer: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution....just needed to watch the next youtube video :-)

I explain what I did so people who might have the same issue in the future know what to do.

In `terminal` I went to my `teamleader-api` folder who is on my desktop.

From https://getcomposer.org/ I copied the code

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === '544e09ee996cdf60ece3804abc52599c22b1f40f4323403c44d44fdfdd586475ca9813a858088ffbc1f233e9b180f061') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Instead of `composer require sumocoders/teamleader` I need to use `php composer.phar require sumocoders/teamleader`

And now it works....easy as pie :-)

Comment: It's by the way not necessary to install Composer for every project. If it is located in `/usr/local/bin` (as described in your question), you should be able to just run `composer.phar <command>` (`<command>` being any of the Composer commands like `require`, `install` etc.).